# Dropbox removed about half of my files

Tags: ubuntu, dropbox

Recently I've started to get message popup message from Dropbox in my Ubuntu that asked me to do something like this:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf; sudo sysctl -p
```

I've used 200000 since 100000 didn't work for me. And this popup stopped to show up, I was happy, it looked like everything syncs just fine. And then I figured out that my Dropbox folder is half smaller than it was. And a lot of files are missing when I'm browsing the folder.

Since I store a lot of text files (programs sources) I can't restore every file manually. Is there any way to restore something like snapshot for the whole folder? I couldn't find this feature.